# How to Integrate GitHub with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: github, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I am moving from a TFS version control environment into GitHub.  I am having difficulty getting my recent VS2019 installation to be aware of the corporate GitHub repository.  I have a GitHub username and access token, however there doesn't appear to be away to integrate this information into VS.  Please note I have no prior experience of working with GitHub.  Our corporate access is served by the following HTTPS statement:

https://github.corp.companyname.com/companyname

Our repositories are managed by a corporate entity who have created the the following entry:

https://github.corp.companyname.com/companyname/reponame

Secure company information in the above https statements have been replaced by generic references 'companyname' and 'reponame'.

I followed instructions in the VS documentation in order to access 'GitHub Enterprise' which seemed like the right thing to do, however when I attempt execute 'Sign in with your browser' it just responds with 'ERR_CONNECT_REFUSED'.

There is currently no content under reponame so logically it appears to me that I owuld need to 'Push' content to the repository.

Hoping all you GitHub gurus out there will come to me swiftly with a workable solution :-)

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: Ok, so I have made some progress towards this, turns out that I needed to add the Visual Studio GitHub extensions from the Installer.  However, having successfully connected to our enterprise GitHub account (with the requisite token), I find that I am unable to push the initial code to the repository.  VS responds with the following error:

Comment: "...Pushing master
Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
unable to access 'https://github.corp.mycompany.com/mycompany/repo/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Pushing to https://github.corp.mycompany.com/mycompany/repo
Failed to push the branch to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details. ..."